# spring boot search with mysql native query with LIKE return empty

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have table with city and country together. I try select city and country name by some first letters with LIKE but everytime it returns empty list. In MySql Workbench this query return result. I try many version but nothing work.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT city, country FROM test8.cities WHERE city LIKE ?'%'", nativeQuery = true)
List<City> findCity(String str);
```

I try and this methods also return empty list.

```
   List<City> findByCityStartsWith(String str);
   List<City> findTop20DistinctByCityIsStartingWith(String str);
```

@Query(value = "SELECT city, country FROM test8.cities WHERE city LIKE ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List findByCityIsStartingWith(String str);

@Query(value = "select city, country FROM test8.cities WHERE city = :str", nativeQuery = true)
List findByCity2(@Param("str")String str);

Comment: Your param str should be something like %someCity% Can you share value of string parameter @Param("str")String str? also, you can use Containing, Contains, IsContaining

Comment: @GetMapping("/cities")
    public @ResponseBody List<City> getCitiesCountry(@RequestParam("searchChars") String searchChars){
        List<States> resultList = countryRepo.findCity(searchChars);
        return resultList;
    }

Comment: What is the value of searchChars? You should wrap it with %. Your query looks like: select city, country FROM test8.cities WHERE city like ‘test’ instead of ‘%test%’

Comment: I select city with first letters every press on input type should get new List of cities so I add +'%'  after ? wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in entity that was changed.